# How to show different images in the particles?

Tags: image, qml, particle-system

I want to *emit particles* but with the images that are in my Array.
I made a modification in my code. The error now is that apparently in function getImage() it's possible to go through all my array getting each path of each image but in ImageParticle it only manages to recognize a single route.
The Result: particles are emitted, but only one image of the twenty that is in the matrix is ​​recognized.
Does anyone know I'm doing wrong?

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Particles 2.0    

Rectangle {
    id: bg
    width: 1920         
    height: 1080         
    color: "black"

    ParticleSystem {
        id: particleSys
    }            

    Emitter{
        id: particles
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        height: 1; width: 1
        system: particleSys
        emitRate: 30
        lifeSpan: 4000
        lifeSpanVariation: 500
        maximumEmitted: 1000
        size: 5
        endSize: 200           

        velocity: TargetDirection{      
            targetX: 100; targetY: 100
            targetVariation: 360
            magnitude: 250
        }            
    }         

    property var picturesList: [
        "images/Image1.png", "images/Image2.png", "images/Image3.png", "images/Image4.png", "images/Image5.png", "images/Image6.png", "images/Image7.png", "images/Image8.png", "images/Image9.png", "images/Image10.png",
        "images/Image11.png", "images/Image12.png", "images/Image13.png", "images/Image14.png", "images/Image15.png", "images/Image16.png", "images/Image17.png", "images/Image18.png", "images/Image19.png", "images/Image20.png"
    ]

    function getImage(arr){
        var flag = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++){                
            flag = arr[i];
            //console.log("Position: " + arr[i] + " flag: " + flag )
        }
        return flag;
    }

    ImageParticle{
        property var link: getImage(picturesList)
        source:  link
        system: particleSys
    }    
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? Generating random number? Use `Math.random() * (max - min) + min`. Getting file list? Use [FolderListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html#details)

Comment: The real problem is that I want 'n' photos (different photos) to come out instead of particles.  

The paths of those photos are in an array but I made a couple of modifications and my problem remains the same: they leave the particles but only recognize an image of all that are in the array.    

In a while I upload the modification of my code.

Comment: I have also researched FolderListModel to implement it and only get the paths of the images in the 'x' folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Particles with different images. \[qml\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44763623/particles-with-different-images-qml)