# Particles with different images. [qml]

Tags: image, qt, qml, particles

I am using **particle systems**. My *particles* come out from the center but *I want different images to come out.*
The file path of these images are stored in an array. I made a function to go through that arrangement and return what is in each position.
What returns is the path of each image to be sent to the **source** of the **ImageParticle.**

The problem is that if you scroll through the entire array but only return the path of the last image and logically I get a single image instead of the twenty that are stored in the array.
Someone could help me?
Help and suggestions are well accepted.

**Here is my code:**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Particles 2.0    

Rectangle {
    id: bg
    width: 1920         //360
    height: 1080            //360
    color: "black"

    ParticleSystem {
        id: particleSys
    }            

    Emitter{
        id: particles
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        height: 1; width: 1
        system: particleSys
        emitRate: 30
        lifeSpan: 4000
        lifeSpanVariation: 500
        maximumEmitted: 1000
        size: 5
        endSize: 200                      

        velocity: TargetDirection{      
            targetX: 100; targetY: 100
            targetVariation: 360
            magnitude: 250
        }            
    }         

    property var picturesList: [
        "images/Image1.png", "images/Image2.png", "images/Image3.png", "images/Image4.png", "images/Image5.png", "images/Image6.png", "images/Image7.png", "images/Image8.png", "images/Image9.png", "images/Image10.png",
        "images/Image11.png", "images/Image12.png", "images/Image13.png", "images/Image14.png", "images/Image15.png", "images/Image16.png", "images/Image17.png", "images/Image18.png", "images/Image19.png", "images/Image20.png"
    ]

    function getImage(arr){
        var flag = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++){                    
            flag = arr[i];
            console.log("Image: " + arr[i] + " flag: " + flag )   //To check if array is traversing.
        }    
        return flag;
    }

    ImageParticle{            
        property var link: getImage(picturesList)
        source: link
        system: particleSys
    }

    // To check which image is returned.
    MouseArea {  
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            console.log(getImage(picturesList))
        }
    }             
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the person who asked the previous question and here I bring the answer.
I know very well that there can be several ways that solve the problem, if you know another way I invite you to share it.
Suggestions about the response are welcome.

Here I share the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Particles 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: bg
    width: 1920         
    height: 1080        
    color: "black"

    ParticleSystem {
        id: particleSys
    }           

    Emitter{
        id: particles
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        height: 1; width: 1
        system: particleSys
        emitRate: 30
        lifeSpan: 4000
        lifeSpanVariation: 500
        maximumEmitted: 1000
        size: 5
        endSize: 200                          

        velocity: TargetDirection{      //4
            targetX: 100; targetY: 100
            targetVariation: 360
            magnitude: 250
        }            
    }         
    property var picturesList: [
        "images/Image1.png", "images/Image2.png", "images/Image3.png", "images/Image4.png", "images/Image5.png", "images/Image6.png", "images/Image7.png", "images/Image8.png", "images/Image9.png", "images/Image10.png",
        "images/Image11.png", "images/Image12.png", "images/Image13.png", "images/Image14.png", "images/Image15.png", "images/Image16.png", "images/Image17.png", "images/Image18.png", "images/Image19.png", "images/Image20.png"
    ]          

    ItemParticle {
        id: particle
        system: particleSys
        delegate: itemDelegate
    }

    Component {
        id: itemDelegate
        Rectangle {
            id: container
            width: 26*Math.ceil(Math.random()*3); height: width
            color: 'white'
            Image {
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: 3
                source: 'images/Image'+Math.ceil(Math.random()*20)+'.png'            
            }
        }
    }            
}
```

As you can see, all the images in the folder will be output.
I simply change the **"ImageParticle"** to **"ItemParticle"** and I *add* a **"Component"** *as a delegate* where the desired image will be.
So we would not use the array (omit it in the previous code) since now only the path of the image is concatenated and a random number (to select the image).
I hope you serve them, and if you have a better implementation, please let them know.